# Google Vision API returns invalid authentication credentials

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, google-cloud-vision

I just developed my system (PHP) using Google Vision API, but when I deployed it to the server (Amazon Elastic Beanstalks) the result showed me that.

"**error code:401 message:Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential**"

For more information 

 - I try to add GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS to AWS EBS environment variables ---> It's not work.

- I try to create client ID and client secret on OAuth consent screen ---> I don't know how to apply it.

Comment: Can you post the request-body? 
Don't forget, you have to include the API key in your request header:
Key:YOUR_API_KEY
In addition, who did you add GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS to your system/server?